# VisualForce version of HTML colspan command

Tags: visualforce

Does anyone know how to get a visualforce page to have text span across 2 columns?  I know the command in HTML would be a colspan command, but I have not been able to find the equivalent in Visualforce.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In what kind of HTML element? A table column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do this in a table, you would use the `colspan` attribute of `<apex:column>`. Quoting from the documentation, [colspan](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_column.htm) represents:

> The number of columns that this column spans in the table. Note that
>   this value does not apply to the header and footer cells.

Example:

```
<apex:datatable value="{! myList}" var="item">
  <apex:column colspan=2 value="{!item.column}"/>
</apex:datatable>
```

**Note**: Keep in mind that you can always apply custom CSS and classes to the apex controls.

Comment: Is there anything I can use with apex:panelgrid?  I would have to complete gut my page if I were changing to apex:datatable.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of and CSS doesn't do colspan.